# How can I iterate through an array of strings using VB?

Tags: arrays, vb6

Here's my code so far:

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim stringArray() as String

stringArray = split("Hello|there", "|")

For i = 0 To stringArray.Length()
   ' Logic goes here
Next
```

VB6 doesn't seem to like me using `stringAray.Length()` and gives me a compile error message like `Invalid Qualifier`, but what's the right way to iterate through each element of a string array?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`ubound()` returns the upper bounds;

```
Dim i As Long
Dim stringArray(1) as String

stringArray(0) = "hello"
stringArray(1) = "world"

For i = 0 To ubound(stringArray)
   msgbox(stringArray(i))
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim stringArray() as String

stringArray = split("Hello|there", "|")

For i = 0 To ubound(stringArray)
   ' Logic goes here
Next
```